# low speed web application, Server problem or Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a web application written by asp.net (c#) sql server 2005. we host it on 2 dedicated server ( IIS and SQL server )
From some month ago , in some days of week we have many reports about speed issue.
we have some other application on this server using same database.
when we have speed problem all aplication on these server have this problem, but applications on other server in same data center work correctly.
ram and cpu usage are ok. how can I check that the problem related to internet connection or my application design? which parameters must be checked.
Some other information 
In applications users can upload several files to server , each file up to 3 MB.
we use a sql web admin application, on same server that has same problem, this is a standard application which work perfectly on other servers.
-Ftp connection also is very slow
- in local area network also application is slow too
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look for DB deadlocks, expensive queries, table scans using SQL Server Activity Monitor and SQL Server Profiler. You can also check number of open connections using perfmon counters. Also, if TCP offloading (chimney) is enabled for the NIC, I would consider disabling that as well.

Comment: Number of connections is not more than 10 connections on DB.on login page which I use Asp.Net Membership also we have a long delay.

Answer (score 0):

> in some days of week ...

=> Do you monitor the web transaction performance over time (e. g. with AlertFox)? Then you can see if the issue reoccurs periodically and at what time/day. If it does, it maybe is a simple issue such as running backup daily, or some other background process?

We had a similar issue with a background db backup that we found and fixed this way.